# Stripe 400 Error "Invalid Positive Integer"

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a real bugger of a question.  I am trying to build a donations page for a nonprofit which charges people through Stripe.  Every charge I try to make gives me an error which reads :

*Parsed Request Post Body*

```
{
    "card"        : "TOKEN WAS HERE",
    "description" : "Donation by   ()",
    "amount"      : "0",
    "currency"    : "usd"
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
    "error" :
    {
        "type"    : "invalid_request_error",
        "message" : "Invalid positive integer",
        "param"   : "amount"
    }
}
```

I *think* there is an issue with the amount I am passing to Stripe (clearly Stripe thinks it is receiving an amount of `0` - I am just not sure if it ACTUALLY is) - but I absolutely CANNOT figure out what it is.  Here is the full extent of the code on my page :

```
<?php
    require( 'Stripe/init.php' );

    // Load configuration settings
    $config = require( 'config.php' );

    // Force https
    if ( $config[ 'test-mode' ] &&
         $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] != 'on' )
    {
        header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
        header( 'Location: https://' .
                    $_SERVER[ "SERVER_NAME" ] .
                    $_SERVER[ "REQUEST_URI" ] );
        exit;
    }

    if ( $_POST )
    {
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey( $config[ 'secret-key' ] );

        // POSTed Variables
        $token      = $_POST[ 'stripeToken' ];
        $first_name = $_POST[ 'first-name' ];
        $last_name  = $_POST[ 'last-name' ];
        $name       = $first_name .
                          ' ' .
                          $last_name;
        $address    = $_POST[ 'address' ] .
                          "\n" .
                          $_POST[ 'city' ] .
                          ', ' .
                          $_POST[ 'state' ] .
                          ' ' .
                          $_POST[ 'zip' ];
        $email      = $_POST[ 'email' ];
        $phone      = $_POST[ 'phone' ];
        $amount     = (float) $_POST[ 'amount' ];

        try
        {
            if ( ! isset( $_POST[ 'stripeToken' ] ) )
            {
                throw new Exception( "The Stripe Token was not generated correctly" );
            }

            // Charge the card
            $donation = \Stripe\Charge::create( array( 'card'        => $token,
                                                       'description' => 'Donation by ' .
                                                                            $name .
                                                                            ' (' .
                                                                            $email .
                                                                            ')',
                                                                        'amount' => $amount * 100,
                                                                        'currency' => 'usd' ) );

            // Build and send the email
            $headers = 'From: ' .
                           $config[ 'email-from' ];

            $headers .= "\r\nBcc: " .
                            $config[ 'email-bcc' ] .
                            "\r\n\r\n";

            // Find and replace values
            $find    = array( '%name%',
                              '%amount%' );

            $replace = array( $name,
                              '$' .
                                  $amount );

            $message = str_replace( $find,
                                    $replace,
                                    $config[ 'email-message' ] ) .
                                        "\n\n";
            $message .= 'Amount: $' .
                            $amount .
                            "\n";

            $message .= 'Address: ' .
                            $address .
                            "\n";

            $message .= 'Phone: ' .
                            $phone .
                            "\n";

            $message .= 'Email: ' .
                            $email .
                            "\n";

            $message .= 'Date: ' .
                            date( 'M j, Y, g:ia',
                                  $donation[ 'created' ] ) .
                                  "\n";

            $message .= 'Transaction ID: ' .
                            $donation['id'] .
                            "\n\n\n";

            $subject = $config[ 'email-subject' ];

            // Send it
            if ( !$config[ 'test-mode' ] )
            {
                mail( $email,
                      $subject,
                      $message,
                      $headers );
            }

            // Forward to "Thank You" page
            header( 'Location: ' .
                    $config[ 'thank-you' ] );
            exit;
        }
        catch ( Exception $e )
        {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

        <script src  = "https://js.stripe.com/v2"
                type = "text/javascript">
        </script>

        <script src  = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"
                type = "text/javascript">
        </script>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            Stripe.setPublishableKey( '<?php echo $config[ 'publishable-key' ] ?>' );
        </script>

        <script src  = "script.js"
                type = "text/javascript" >
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "wrapper">
            <div class = "messages">
                <!-- Error messages go here go here -->
            </div>

            <form action = "#"
                  class  = "donation-form"
                  id     = "donor"
                  method = "POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        Contact Information
                    </legend>

                    <div class = "form-row form-first-name">
                        <label>
                            First Name
                        </label>

                        <input class = "first-name text"
                               name  = "first-name"
                               type  = "text">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-last-name">
                        <label>
                            Last Name
                        </label>

                        <input class = "last-name text"
                               name  = "last-name"
                               type  = "text">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-email">
                        <label>
                            Email
                        </label>

                        <input class = "email text"
                               name  = "email"
                               type  = "text">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-phone">
                        <label>
                            Phone
                        </label>

                        <input class = "phone text"
                               name  = "phone"
                               type  = "text">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-address">
                        <label>
                            Address
                        </label>

                        <textarea class = "address text"
                                  name  = "address"
                                  cols  = "30"
                                  rows  = "2">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-city">
                        <label>
                            City
                        </label>

                        <input class = "city text"
                               name  = "city"
                               type  = "text">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-state">
                        <label>
                            State
                        </label>

                        <select name = "state" class="state text">
                            <option value = "AL">
                                AL
                            </option>

                            <option value = "AK">
                                AK
                            </option>

                            <option value = "AZ">
                                AZ
                            </option>

                            <option value = "AR">
                                AR
                            </option>

                            <option value = "CA">
                                CA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "CO">
                                CO
                            </option>

                            <option value = "CT">
                                CT
                            </option>

                            <option value = "DE">
                                DE
                            </option>

                            <option value = "DC">
                                DC
                            </option>

                            <option value = "FL">
                                FL
                            </option>

                            <option value = "GA">
                                GA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "HI">
                                HI
                            </option>

                            <option value = "ID">
                                ID
                            </option>

                            <option value = "IL">
                                IL
                            </option>

                            <option value = "IN">
                                IN
                            </option>

                            <option value = "IA">
                                IA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "KS">
                                KS
                            </option>

                            <option value = "KY">
                                KY
                            </option>

                            <option value = "LA">
                                LA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "ME">
                                ME
                            </option>

                            <option value = "MD">
                                MD
                            </option>

                            <option value = "MA">
                                MA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "MI">
                                MI
                            </option>

                            <option value = "MN">
                                MN
                            </option>

                            <option value = "MS">
                                MS
                            </option>

                            <option value = "MO">
                                MO
                            </option>

                            <option value = "MT">
                                MT
                            </option>

                            <option value = "NE">
                                NE
                            </option>

                            <option value = "NV">
                                NV
                            </option>

                            <option value = "NH">
                                NH
                            </option>

                            <option value = "NJ">
                                NJ
                            </option>

                            <option value = "NM">
                                NM
                            </option>

                            <option value = "NY">
                                NY
                            </option>

                            <option value = "NC">
                                NC
                            </option>

                            <option value = "ND">
                                ND
                            </option>

                            <option value = "OH">
                                OH
                            </option>

                            <option value = "OK">
                                OK
                            </option>

                            <option value = "OR">
                                OR
                            </option>

                            <option value = "PA">
                                PA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "RI">
                                RI
                            </option>

                            <option value = "SC">
                                SC
                            </option>

                            <option value = "SD">
                                SD
                            </option>

                            <option value = "TN">
                                TN
                            </option>

                            <option value = "TX">
                                TX
                            </option>

                            <option value = "UT">
                                UT
                            </option>

                            <option value = "VT">
                                VT
                            </option>

                            <option value = "VA">
                                VA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "WA">
                                WA
                            </option>

                            <option value = "WV">
                                WV
                            </option>

                            <option value = "WI">
                                WI
                            </option>

                            <option value = "WY">
                                WY
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-zip">
                        <label>
                            Zip
                        </label>

                        <input class = "zip text"
                               name  = "zip"
                               type  = "text">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        Your Generous Donation
                    </legend>

                    <div class = "form-row form-amount">
                        <label>
                            <input class = "set-amount"
                                   name  = "amount"
                                   type  = "radio"
                                   value = "10">
                                $10
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <input class = "set-amount"
                                   name  = "amount"
                                   type  = "radio"
                                   value = "27">
                                $27
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <input class = "set-amount"
                                   name  = "amount"
                                   type  = "radio"
                                   value = "50">
                                $50
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <input class = "set-amount"
                                   name  = "amount"
                                   type  = "radio"
                                   value = "100">
                                $100
                        </label>

                        <label>
                            <input class = "other-amount"
                                   name  = "amount"
                                   type  = "radio"
                                   value = "0">
                                Other:
                        </label>

                        <input type="text" class="amount text" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row form-number">
                        <label>
                            Card Number
                        </label>

                        <input class        = "card-number text"
                               autocomplete = "off"
                               type         = "text"
                               value        = "">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-row form-cvc">
                        <label>
                            CVC
                        </label>

                        <input class        = "card-cvc text"
                               autocomplete = "off"
                               type         = "text"
                               value        = "">
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-expiry">
                        <label>
                            Expiration Date
                        </label>

                        <select class="card-expiry-month text">
                            <option selected
                                    value = "01">
                                January
                            </option>

                            <option value = "02">
                                February
                            </option>

                            <option value = "03">
                                March
                            </option>

                            <option value = "04">
                                April
                            </option>

                            <option value = "05">
                                May
                            </option>

                            <option value = "06">
                                June
                            </option>

                            <option value = "07">
                                July
                            </option>

                            <option value = "08">
                                August
                            </option>

                            <option value = "09">
                                September
                            </option>

                            <option value = "10">
                                October
                            </option>

                            <option value = "11">
                                November
                            </option>

                            <option value = "12">
                                December
                            </option>
                        </select>

                        <select class = "card-expiry-year text">
                            <option selected
                                    value = "2017">
                                2017
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2018">
                                2018
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2019">
                                2019
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2020">
                                2020
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2021">
                                2021
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2022">
                                2022
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2023">
                                2023
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2024">
                                2024
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2025">
                                2025
                            </option>

                            <option value = "2026">
                                2026
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class = "form-row form-submit">
                        <input class = "submit-button"
                               type  = "submit"
                               value = "Submit Donation">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script>
            if ( window.Stripe ) $('.donation-form').show()
        </script>

        <noscript>
            <p>
                JavaScript is required for the donation form.
            </p>
        </noscript>
    </body>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

    <script src = 'google-sheet.js'>
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked what is being sent to them? What is the actual value?

Comment: I am not sure - I am rather inexperienced at PHP. I know that I typed 1 into my donation box, so I am trying to send a value of 1, and I know Stripe is receiving a value of 0. I'm not sure where it gets lost in between.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending amount 0 which stripe take as a non-positive number. Even mathematically 0 is not a positive integer neither is a negative integer.
I just faced this issue and turns out that I was also sending 0 in amount. Sending amount greater than 0 works fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know php so may be way off here, but it looks as though you are declaring the amount as a floating number.  Multiplying by 100 shouldn't change this so you may need to actually convert it to an integer before sending.

(I'm guessing you are sending 123.0000.... rather than 123)

Comment: To my knowledge PHP is a dynamic type system, so PHP will convert the type as needed. I could be off base since I am an amateur programmer, but I believe this isn't an issue.

Comment: Alright, and just because I have no idea what I'm doing, I did try converting to integer and I got the same error

Comment: Can you try logging the data type of the amount and the value, immediately before/after sending?

Comment: It needs to be at least 100,

Comment: The odd thing is that your parsed request shows the amount as a string and it would be expected to be an integer.